# Automate exporting MATLAB figure plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Is it possible to automate the exporting of plots to give me the same results as when I enlarge aplot to full screen, go to file and save as PNG. I have experimented with `set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 50 21.0])` and **print** but all the lines end up thicker and the plot is not as clear even with a high resolution. I would prefer to avoid using export_fig. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just enlarge the plot programmatically and then save it? e.g. `set(get(gcf,'JavaFrame'),'Maximized',true);`

Comment: What code do you use for printing? Your `set` line followed by `print filename -dpng` gives pretty good resolution (2953 x 1240 pixels) on my system (Matlab R2014b, Windows 7)

Comment: @ Dev-iL  Is there a way to save the plot figure programmatically to png. I thought it could only be done through the file menu.

Comment: @Luis Mendo  my plot code is `set(gcf,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 50 21.0])
print('-dpng', 'Margin_Plot.png', '-r300);`  Resolution isn't the problem. It's that it's change the thickness of lines, font's, etc

Comment: You can save it as png. But the image quality will lose. You have to export the figure as png to maintain a reasonable quality.

Comment: Can you post the code that includes figure creation also?